# Storing custom types in systemverilog header files

Tags: system-verilog

I have a whole bunch of custom types that I use throughout my systemverilog code.

Currently I have copies of the typedefs in each file, however it would be great if I could specify the typedef in the header file and just include one header file in each module. This would save me from having to maintain multiple copies of the typedefs and also would clean up my code significantly.

I have tried to do this, by pasting the typedef into the header file, however the tools (Vivado 2014.1) do not like the fact that the typedef is outside of the module and I get syntax errors.

Is there a syntax I can use to specify typedefs that are common to multiple modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define all your types inside a `package` and simply import them wherever you want in your code.

For example:

```
package ComplexPkg;
  typedef struct{
    shortreal i, r;
  } Complex;
endpackage: ComplexPkg
```

And then:

```
import ComplexPkg::Complex;
```

More information about `packages` you can find in [IEEE 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), p. 738.